# PySpark Dataframes: how to filter on multiple conditions with compact code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a list of column names and I want to filter on rows if the value of those columns are greater than zero, is there something similar to this which I can do?

```
columns = ['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE','colF']
new_df = df.filter(any([df[c]>0 for c in columns]))
```

This returns:

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and',
>   '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean
>   expressions

I guess I can sum those columns and the filter on only one column (since I don't have negative numbers. But if I had the sum-trick wouldn't work. And anyway if I had to filter those columns on another condition different than the sum, how could I do what I want to do?
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `or_` operator instead :

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

newdf = df.where(reduce(or_, (df[c] > 0 for c in df.columns)))
```

**EDIT:** More pythonista solution :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

def any_(*preds):
    cond = lit(False)
    for pred in preds:
        cond = cond | pred
    return cond

newdf = df.where(any_(*[df[c] > 0 for c in df.columns]))
```

**EDIT 2:** Full example :

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015 11:16:01)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

In [1]: from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

In [2]: %pas
%paste     %pastebin  

In [2]: %paste
def any_(*preds):
    cond = lit(False)
    for pred in preds:
        cond = cond | pred
    return cond

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: df = sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3), (-1, -2, -3), (1, -1, 0)]).toDF()

In [4]: df.where(any_(*[df[c] > 0 for c in df.columns])).show()
# +---+---+---+
# | _1| _2| _3|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|
# |  1| -1|  0|
# +---+---+---+

In [5]: df[any_(*[df[c] > 0 for c in df.columns])].show()
# +---+---+---+
# | _1| _2| _3|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|
# |  1| -1|  0|
# +---+---+---+

In [6]: df.show()
# +---+---+---+
# | _1| _2| _3|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|
# | -1| -2| -3|
# |  1| -1|  0|
# +---+---+---+
```